# How to convert the first letter capitalized value of an array to lower case

Tags: php, arrays, database, string

I have a form

> **Name :** i.e in form (name = "detail[name]")
>
> **Address :** i.e in form (name = "detail[address]")
>
> **Email :** i.e in form (name = "detail[email]")

I fetched the data as follows in php:

> **$data** = array_map('ucwords', $_POST['detail']);

I got all the values with capitalized first letter in my database after using insert query

Then I have realized that email should not be in caps so I thought of converting it to lowercase while making sure other values remains constant

And I failed ... so anyone interested to help me is most welcomed :D

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple: PHP's [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/strtolower) function.

`$lower = strtolower($value)`

Comment: you didn't get me ...... thanks for reply though ....... I am using dynamic query so can't do that ....... strtolower (I think)..

Comment: Isn't email always in `$data['email']`?

Comment: @kingkero - exactly, I see nothing dynamic about this.

Comment: to get the query executed I need to make sure that the required data are in an array format

Answer (score 0):

you can use a foreach to make the changes of all your posted values like

```
  $detail = $_POST['detail'];
  $arr = array();
  foreach($detail as $key => $value){

       if($key != 'email'){
           $arr[$key] = ucword($value);
        } else {
           $arr[$key] = $value;
        }

  }
```

Now what will happen is you will get a new array $arr which you can store directly into your databse which dont have email with first letter CAPS

Comment: I wish I could have done this but my query is dynamic and I need to make sure that it is in array format to get the query executed.

Comment: It will work in any dynamic query because every time it checks for only email only not for every fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to obtain first letter in small:

```
$email = strtolower($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use **`ucwords`** then ?

```
$data = array_map('ucwords', $_POST['detail']);
```

That will make your contents inside the `$_POST['detail']` to be in UPPER case. Just don't use it.

Remove the `array_map` and `ucwords` and just do like this.

```
$data =  $_POST['detail'];
```

Comment: And then use `$data['email'] = strtolower($data['email']);` as mentioned in several answers.

Comment: @Stanyer, Nope no need for that. His content is getting capitalized since he is using the `ucwords()` in the `array_map()`

Comment: @shankar I need the values in systematic format so I have to use ucwords

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I believe he said he explicitly wanted the email as lower case, and the user input may not always be in lowercase?

Comment: @rt8s that still doesn't mean you can't use `$data['email'] = strtolower($data['email']);`

Comment: @stanyer I can use that but then I have to again assign it to my $data variable which holds the rest of the data then only I can use update query

Comment: Why do you have to re-assign it to your $data array? We're working directly on the element of the $data array...

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = strtolower($email);
```

Its very simple.But u are saying its dynamic can u please elaborate or paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the whole word to lowercase then just use:

```
$oldString = "Something";
$newString = $strtolower($oldString);
```

Otherwise if you want to strictly convert only the first letter you can use:

```
$oldString = "SOMETHING";
$newString = $strtolower($substr($oldString, 0, 1)) . $substr($oldString, 1);
```